# Set OpenXava (NaviOX) initial page to a custom JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, frameworks, openxava

I have an OpenXava web application. By default, it loads the last module I have opened as initial page. I need to change that behavior making the initial page some custom JSP page.

I have set AutoLogin in **naviox-users.properties** and tried to change the initial page into **Modules.java** as follows:

```
private static void createFirstStepsModule(String applicationName) {
    MetaApplication app = MetaApplications.getMetaApplication(applicationName);
    MetaModule firstStepsModule = new MetaModule();
    firstStepsModule.setName(FIRST_STEPS); 
    firstStepsModule.setModelName("SignIn"); 
    firstStepsModule.setWebViewURL("/naviox/myPage.jsp"); //My page goes here...
    firstStepsModule.setModeControllerName("Void");
    app.addMetaModule(firstStepsModule);        
}
```

However, OpenXava is still openning the last module page. Does anyone know how to properly set the initial OpenXava page to a custom JSP page?

I am using OpenXava 5.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify index.jsp to forward your initial page.